# How can I dampen the sound of maracas?

Tags: dynamics, percussion, mute

I bought these [Meinl PM1BK Studio Maracas](https://www.musik-produktiv.ch/meinl-pm1bk-studio-maracas.html?gad_source=1).  They are way too loud for me. Just way too loud. I kinda need to wear ear protection to use them.

Now… is there a way to easily dampen the sound of the maracas? I don't mind if they look ugly afterwards; they are just unusable for me currently.

Could I tape something to them? Or drill a hole and put some liquid in them, maybe? I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: Wait, have you tried anything already? I find that pretty much any “rattle“ type of percussion can be dampened simply by touching the shell. You could try holding the “rattly“ part instead of the handle.

Comment: I tried that, but its still way too loud. It doesnt HURT any longer, but it is still way too loud. If I wrap a cloth around it like a shirt, its still too loud. If I put it inside the thick plastic bag it came in, then its good. But... I dont want to be shaking my maracas in the plastic bag right. Apart from that I have only one plastic

Comment: Regarding the suggested edit: it is acceptable to use "dampen" like this.

Answer (score 6):

Pretty much anything touching or covering the shell will lower the volume.  One thing I think to try is a party balloon.  Cut the narrowest part off (where you inflate it/ tie it off) and stretch the rest over the shell.  You can double or triple layer if you need.  Tape is an option but will probably leave some glue residue which can be messy, unless you first do a balloon layer and then tape on top of that.

If it's just the sound of Maracas you want, at a quieter volume, the best approach might be to not use Maracas and instead grab some egg shakers with a coarse filling.  The playing technique will be different, but the sound will be similar.

Answer (score 3):

Nice pair of woolly socks. Especially if you're in the Northern hemisphere right now.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could modify your playing technique to shake them up, and down. They should sound less abrasive if you supply the beads less energy